# Power BI Exporting data to a excel/csv

Tags: powerbi, pivot-table, export-to-excel

Is there way to export data from powerBi to excel or csv file? I tried analyze to excel, but unfortunately analyze with excel works with meassures and not calculated meassures.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: By "calculated meassures" do you mean [implicit measures](https://radacad.com/explicit-vs-implicit-dax-measures-in-power-bi)?

Answer (score 1):

Ther are 2 ways in Power BI online to export data to excel. Either directly from a **visual**, or from the underlying **dataset**.

1. When you mouse over the upper area of a visual you get an additional menu with e.g. the drill icons and on the right hand side there is an ellipsis with additional options. From there you can select **Export data** and you can chose between *summarized* and *underlying* data and this will then be dumped into an Excel (or csv) file. Unfortunately there is a 150.000 rows (csv: 30.000 rows) limit and you only get the data from that has been used in that specific visual.
2. When you look at the top menu of the whole report there is another **Export** button, that allows you to analyze the whole data model of that report in Excel ([Analyze in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-analyze-in-excel)). This feature establishes a live OLAP connection to the Power BI dataset and you can access the data via the PivotTable Fields pane.  The specialty here is that the data has been categorized into columns, with a small list icon, and measures, with a sigma symbol. Now the rule is that you can use **columns** (or **calculated columns**) only in the **Filters**, **Columns** or **Rows** area of a pivot table and the **measures** only in the **Values** area.

A problem in the 2nd approach are **implicit measures** from Power BI. This is a Power BI internal feature that is not propagated into Excel, so implicit measure behave just like columns, which is in general not what you want. The solution is straight forward though: **In Power BI replace all implicit measures with explicit ones** by defining your desired aggregation using a simple DAX expression (Sum(), Count(), Max(), …). Note that when you hide your implicit measures later on from the Fields pane, they will neither show up on the Excel interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can download data from visualization in excel or csv format.

Top right corner in the dropdown you will have option to export data, from that you can choose to export csv or excel.

What kind of analyse you need ?