# Refresh an Excel Report that comes from PBI

Tags: excel, powerbi, connection, refresh

I have a page on PowerBI that I did not develop, but I can download data straight to excel. This data needs to be filtered on PBI first before anything, as it contains sensitive information that I will be eventually sending to an external partner. What I want to be able to do is download this report to excel one time and create pivot tables, with all of the necessary filters added, and be able to just click refresh on the excel file and have it update (PBI file currently updates daily). My end goal is to send this information to a vendor and all I will need to do is hit refresh so that I may send to them. I am lost on how to do this, so if anybody can help I will greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or have errors. Reading [ask] and [repro] should help you to improve your question.

Comment: So far I have tried the analyze in excel feature in powerbi but this does not refresh the information, and also looks like none of the data was filtered. I have also tried to add a connection to PBI from my excel file but I got stuck there.

Comment: Like this your question is too broad ... try to get some more knowledge about the whole topic and then start asking specific questions.

Comment: I did, someone else was able to answer my questions perfectly. Maybe I was just unclear in what I was asking to you, but I did get what I was looking for from somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Analyze in Excel is exactly the way to go. Find more information here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-analyze-in-excel

You'll get a live connection to your Power BI dataset and you can use pivot tables to filter the data to your needs. And for sure the data is updated when you hit the refresh button.

To play it save you could finally remove the data connection from the workbook so that the data is frozen and there is no access to sensitive information.

See also my answer here regarding common Analyze in Excel pitfalls:
[Power BI Exporting data to a excel/csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69437098/power-bi-exporting-data-to-a-excel-csv/69438424#69438424)

Comment: I need more reputation first before it allows me to do so.